# Swift 2.0 - stringByAppendingPathComponent error conversion

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift2

I have updated Xcode to 7 all my apps, after the conversion from swift to swift 2.0, got errors that after a bit of research I was able to manually fix them.

However, I have an error with 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' that I cannot solve. It seems that swift 2.0 removed this method.

The picture attached shows the error I am tiling about.

[image]

Any Idea how to solve this issue?

```
func loadNotes(){


        let plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let DocumentsDirectory = plistPath[0] as! String
        let path = DocumentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("notes.plist")
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {

            if let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("notes", ofType: "plist") {

                let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)
                println("Bundle notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
                fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundlePath, toPath: path, error: nil)
                println("copy")

            } else {
                println("notes.plist not found")
            }


        }else {
            println("note.plist already exists")

            //fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
        }

        let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        println("Loaded notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
        var myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

        if let dict = myDict {
            //load values

        } else {

            println("worning ccould not create dictionary from notes.plist, default values will be used")
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is a lot of swift 1.2 code - no more println

Comment: Try using the convert to latest swift syntax option

Comment: Hi Jeef yes I attached 1.2 - I have tried to use convert to latest swift syntax option but the error is not changing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apple wants you to use URLs instead of paths so they have made it unavailable in Swift 2. If you don't want to use `NSURL`, you can temporarily cast it to `NSString` instead:

```
let path = (DocumentsDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("notes.plist")
```

Comment: Never convert String to NSString. See what is prescribed by Apple.

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/adc54c8a4d13fbebfeb68244bac401ef2528d6d0/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSStringAPI.swift#L1345